# System x3650 Hard Drive Upgrade

Tags: exchange-2007, hardware-raid, ibm-xseries

I have a IBM System x3650 Server with 6 Storage Bays (6 Drives). I am planning / have to change 2 hard drives.

Do they have to be some sort of specific drives or can I just order 10K SAS 750 or 500GB Hard Drives ?
I have tried looking up on IBM. The Raid Manager which is installed on our server says "Serial Attached SCSI" so that means they are SAS Drives ?

If there is anything you think I should consider before purchasing and changing drives ?

Also, these TWO Disks are in a RAID-1, I will just switch off the server and pull these ones out, put the new ONEs (2 Disks) in and Build RAID-1 on it, format it NTFS and restore our Exchange DBs onto it.

Any thoughts or suggestions ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Because you are replacing all the drives in the Logical Volume (Sounds like you are) this should work.

Check the specs on your RAID controller as some have maximum supported drive sizes.

Serial attached SCSI is the full description of 'SAS' so yes they are SAS drives.

Comment: Thanks Nick, Once I have changed the drives, I will use BESR to restore Just the Exchange 2007 Mailbox DB onto the new one and then reboot the server hoping it will pick the DB fine. I hope exchange dbs don't tie up with any disk guid or id.. just reassuring. Thanks

Comment: Also, the disks installed at the moment are SAS 3GBps, new ones available on IBM website are SAS 6GBps. I am only going to change Two (2) disks on this server - would that be ok ? or it may create some sort of conflict? these two NEW disks would be in a RAID-1 so they won't be in a raid with a slow or a faster disk - Thanks

Comment: Check with IBM on the 3Gbps / 6Gbps question; I dont know if you're existing controller will support SAS6 (not usually backwards compatible)